# Нужно написать программу присваивания переменных к задаче в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, переменные

Суть задачи - Две переменные типа A и B. Если их значения не равны, то присвоить каждой переменной большее из этих значений, а если равны, то присвоить переменным нулевые значения. Вывести новые значения переменных A и B..

Заранее спасибо вам за ответ!

Comment: Ну, как я и говорил, скоро так дойдёт до вопросов "Напишите программу, считающую A+B"

Comment: `a,b=map(int,input().split())
a=b=max(a, b)*(a!=b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это наилегчайшая задача, но без лишних слов, вот код:

```
a, b = int(input()), int(input())

if a != b:
    c = max(a, b)
    a, b = c, c
else:
   a, b = 0, 0

print(a, b)
```